# Finding sum and grouping in sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a donations table as follows.

**Donations Table**

```
| id| amount | member_id |
|---|--------|-----------|
| 0 |   500  |         01|
| 1 |  1000  |         02|
| 2 |  2000  |         01|
```

How to find sum and group the table by member id as follows.

```
| amount | member_id |
|--------|-----------|
|  2500  |         01|
|  1000  |         02|
```

I tried to use the following code but it doesnt seem to work.

```
const salesValue = await DONATIONS.sum('amount', {
    group: 'member_id'
});
```

Comment: It would be very simple in a sql way, `select member_id,sum(amount) from Donations group by member_id` , but you want implement this in a `node.js` way?

Comment: Yes i am aware that doing it using pure sql queries is easier but i hope to have uniformity in my app and since im using sequelize ORM i'd like to implement this functionality using sequelize as well.

Answer (score 57):

You have to do an aggregation using `sequelize.fn`. To target the amount column you have to use `sequelize.col` and to group them you have to pass the `group` option.

```
const totalAmount = await DONATIONS.findAll({
        attributes: [
          'member_id',
          [sequelize.fn('sum', sequelize.col('amount')), 'total_amount'],
        ],
        group: ['member_id'],
      });
```

Comment: you should add text if possible to explain your answer

Comment: When I do this, I can't access totalAmount. It is an object with `dataValues` etc. How do you get the number?

Answer (score 6):

if you want to get the value directly add the property: `raw: true`

```js
const totalAmount = await DONATIONS.findAll({
  attributes: [
    'member_id',
    [sequelize.fn('sum', sequelize.col('amount')), 'total_amount'],
  ],
  group: ['member_id'],
  raw: true
});
```