# Finding sum and grouping by associated table values in sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a donations table as follows.

**Donations Table**

```
| id| amount | member_id |
|---|--------|-----------|
| 1 |   500  |         01|
| 2 |  1000  |         02|
| 3 |  2000  |         03|
```

**Members Table**

```
| id | name   | team_id   |
|----|--------|-----------|
| 01 |  tom   |         02|
| 02 |  jerry |         01|
| 03 |  jane  |         01|
```

**Team Table**

```
| id | name   |
|----|--------|
| 01 |  TeamA |
| 02 |  TeamB |
```

How to find sum and group the table by team as follows.

```
| amount | amount    |
|--------|-----------|
|  TeamA |       3000|
|  TeamB |        500|
```

I tried to use the following code but it doesnt seem to work.

```
const totalAmount = await DONATIONS.findAll({
  attributes: [
    'member_id',
    [sequelize.fn('sum', sequelize.col('amount')), 'total_amount'],
  ],
  include:[
    {
      model: MEMBERS,
      include:[
        {
          model:TEAMS,
          group:['name']
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
});
```

> This is not a duplicate of [this question I've asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56538035/finding-sum-and-grouping-in-sequelize)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to handle it in the mysql side:

```
SELECT
    MAX(t.name) AS TeamName,
    SUM(d.amount) AS TotalAmount
FROM team t
INNER JOIN members m ON t.id = m.team_id
INNER JOIN donations d ON m.id = d.member_id
GROUP BY t.id
;
```

Comment: Isn't there  away to do it using the sequelize syntax instead of raw queries ?

Comment: @Muljayan I don't know. Perhaps check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20460270/7032856) out.